# Express Middleware just to handle requests between React and Python

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a react-app and a python backend. The python API runs on "https://comapny-api.com". I define the URL in my .env file. Now I would like to implement a Node.js server in the middle. I just want that nodejs server to get the request from the client and send  it to the python side and return back the response sent by the backend to the client. The only reason I am doing this is that I do not want anyone to know the final API endpoint I hit. In the network tab, I show the nodejs server URL so the end user is unaware of the final API endpoint. Is my approach a good one to take? If yes, can I write just a single method using express to handle  this? Please advice.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('root')
})
```

Will this template work? For example, if I call https://nodejsserver.com/years, will it hit this '/' GET endpoint and in turn call in my final API /years endpoint. I am wondering how can I call a generic endpoint in express, one for get and one for post and get the URL from req.params and call the python API with req.params. Thanks

Comment: pipe req into a http client and its response into res

Comment: Can you provide me an example buddy?

Comment: You seem to be describing a *proxy*, I'd recommend research around that concept.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe . Will do.

Comment: `app.all('/*', (req, res) => {
    somehttpclient(req.url.substr(1), req.method, req.body).then(resp => res.json(resp))
})`

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone . Will try it out and report back.

Comment: What you want is called a "proxy" there are ready-to-use node libs, as example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxy

Answer (score 0):

If you have clear react-app without server logic, you can build react-app as js bundle and use it as static, and your python backend becomes the only web-server.

This approach advantage is infrastructure simplification (minus one backend and you still can debug your front separately), but some server logic can become more expensive, like ssr and routing.

Comment: Thats the current stand as of now. But we want an infrastructure wherein the backend API endpoint isnt visible to the end consumer at all. I have a working model now with express. Should test the scalability now.